# A sentence I found in Im Westen nichts neues

Tags: english-to-german

Sogar für abends hat jeder noch ein Kochgeschirr voll fassen können;

I am having difficulty with understanding this sentence well. Perhaps an extremely literal translation coupled with how the meaning functions in the sentence?
Much appreciated and vielen dank!

Comment: Womit bestehen denn Schwierigkeiten? Die Vokabel 'Kochgeschirr'? Die Phrase 'essen fassen'? Was sonst?

Answer (score 4):

Kochgeschirr kann die Ausrüstung mit Töpfen und Pfannen zum Kochen sein, ist aber auch der Begriff für eine Gefäßkombination, die von Armee und Abenteuerurlaubern verwendet wird, bei der man die Gefäße sowohl zum Kochen auf offenem Feuer, Herd oder Gaskocher verwenden kann, als auch direkt aus diesen 1-Personen-Töpfen isst. Da man nicht mehrfach Geschirr mitführt wird aus diesen Gefäßen auch gegessen, wenn im großen Topf für alle gekocht wird.

Bild: 
http://www.survival-outdoor-shop.eu/Bundeswehr-Kochgeschirr-3-teilig-neu

Bei Armee und Pfadfindern wird das Abholen der Portion, die man isst, 'Essen fassen' genannt.

> Sogar für abends hat jeder noch eine Portion abholen können.

Es gab also wohl eine Portion für sofort (zum Mittagessen, mutmaßlich) und noch eine Portion für abends - die man dann vielleicht kalt verzehren musste oder sich autonom aufgewärmt hat.

Answer (score 1):

Er benutzt das Kochgeschirr, das die Soldaten benutzen, um ihre Mahlzeiten zu essen, als eine Art von Maßstab.

Im „normalen“, täglichen Leben benutzt man Ausdrücke wie „ein Glas voll Bier“ oder „einen Teller voll Nudeln“, um die Größe einer Portion darzustellen.

Die Soldaten hatten sogenanntes „Kochgeschirr“ statt „normaler“ Teller etc. Also verwendet er das als Maßstab.

Wenn ich sagen würde: „Wir hatten soviel zu essen da, dass es für mittags reichte. Und am Abend hat sich jeder noch einmal einen Teller nehmen können.“
Das würde ungefähr das Gleiche ausdrücken.

Answer (score 0):

User unknown and user20582 are right about the meaning, but I guess you need help parsing the sentence. In particular, "voll" is tricky: it is part of a phrase "ein Kochgeschirr voll", not "voll fassen". Also the phrase "für abends [Essen] fassen" has been split into two parts and a core part removed.

I think everything should be clear from an extremely literal translation that preserves the original word order:

> Even for in-the-evening has everyone still a mess-kit full seize could.

I used non-standard hyphens where several English words translate one German word. After dropping this, correcting word order and correcting *has could* to *was able to*:

> Even for in the evening, everyone was still able to seize a mess kit full.

Finally a proper but clumsy translation, staying much closer to the original than what one would normally do when translating a novel:

> There was even enough for everyone to secure a mess kit full for the evening.